# Не понимаю как реализовать

Tags: c++, c

шахматная доска представим символьной матрицей размера 8x8. заданные
натуральные числа n и m, которые определяют номера вертикали и горизонтали
местонахождение ферзя. Соответствующий элемент матрицы нужно заменить
символом Ф. Поля, находящихся под угрозой ферзя заменить символом *,
другие - символом 0. Отпечатать полученную матрицу.

Comment: @Harry 
помогите пожалуйста

Comment: Создаете 8*8 матрицу, забиваете нулями. Ставите ферзя, смотрите куда пробивает, забиваете эти клетки звездочками. Какой вопрос такой ответ :)

Comment: @SelfishCrawler можете написать код буду очень благодарен

Comment: @Harry можете помочь просто у меня еще осталось 20 минут и я вообще не знаю что делать

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Схему описал [@Harry](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/195342/harry), поэтому я предоставлю лишь код.

```
#include <iostream>

int main(){

    int n, m; //n - строка, m - столбец
    std::cin >> n >> m; --n; --m;
    char** field = new char*[8];
    for(int i=0; i<8; ++i, std::cout << '\n'){
        field[i] = new char[8];
        for(int j=0; j<8; std::cout << field[i][j++] << ' ')
            if(i==n && j==m) field[i][j] = 'Ф';
            else if((i==n) || (j==m) || (i+j == m+n) || (i-j == n-m)) field[i][j] = '*';
            else field[i][j] = '0';
    }
    return 0;
}
```

UPD:

```
#include <iostream>

int main(){
    int n, m; //n - строка, m - столбец
    std::cin >> n >> m; --n; --m;
    char** field = new char*[8];
    for(int i=0; i<8; ++i){
        field[i] = new char[8];
        for(int j=0; j<8;){
            if(i==n && j==m) field[i][j] = 'Ф';
            else if((i==n) || (j==m) || (i+j == m+n) || (i-j == n-m)) field[i][j] = '*';
            else field[i][j] = '0';
            std::cout << field[i][j++] << ' ';
        }
        std::cout << '\n';
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: И еще ферзя выделить буквой `Ф`. И все же не стоит делать домашку за кого-то полностью, не лишайте человека радости творчества...

Comment: @Harry забыл про букву Ф, но как видите код "специфичный", поэтому если препод спросит, то будет тяжко

Comment: где нужно добавить Ф и как вывести эту матрицу

Comment: @fbbbadasdasdvdvsadvsadv уже все готово. и вывод, и буква Ф.

Comment: кажется вывод не работает?

Comment: @fbbbadasdasdvdvsadvsadv а вы проверили ? кажется или не работает ?

Comment: не работает проверял в visual studio

Comment: @fbbbadasdasdvdvsadvsadv у меня все прекрасно работает. (CodeBlocks)

Comment: у вас тоже visual studio?

Comment: @fbbbadasdasdvdvsadvsadv я использую Code::Blocks

Comment: оно просто выводит пустую консоль

Comment: @fbbbadasdasdvdvsadvsadv напиши в начале программы (перед строкой `int n,m;...`) `std::cout << "Hello\n";` и скажите что будет

Comment: вывело Hello...

Comment: @fbbbadasdasdvdvsadvsadv попробуйте новый код (из UPD)

Comment: так же
можете дать ссылку на какие-то онлайн компилятор чтобы вывел

Comment: @fbbbadasdasdvdvsadvsadv да хоть https://ideone.com/l/cpp

Comment: не работает ссылка

Comment: @fbbbadasdasdvdvsadvsadv если ошибка 503 - VPN в помощь. можете сами найти другой компилятор, это не сложно.

Comment: оно должно вывести все нули?

Comment: на компиляторе выводит все нули

Comment: @fbbbadasdasdvdvsadvsadv проверьте ваш ввод в stdin графе выбранного вами компилятора.

Comment: мы должны ввести 2 цифры и что они означают?

Comment: @fbbbadasdasdvdvsadvsadv прочитайте ваше ТЗ и поймете, я не намерен разъяснять вам ваше же ТЗ.

Comment: символ Ф тоже должна отражаться?

Comment: почему выводить поле 4 на 8?

Comment: если у вас все работает скиньте скрин на почту пожалуйста akvasnuk@gmail.com

Comment: пришлите на почту пожалуйста

Answer (score 1):

Как ходит ферзь? По горизонтали (под боем все клетки, у которых номер строки совпадает с m), по вертикали (под боем все клетки, у которых номер столбца совпадает с n), по диагонали (разность координаты по вертикали и по горизонтали такая же, как у ферзя) и по второй диагонали (сумма координат по вертикали и по горизонтали такая же, как у ферзя).

Все. Просто обходите все клетки доски, проверяйте выполнение любого из условий, и помечайте клетки соответствующим образом.

Comment: можете написать код, я что-то не очень понимаю?

Comment: можете написать код буду очень благодарен

Comment: можете помочь просто у меня еще осталось 20 минут и я вообще не знаю что делать